# Trying to add a value into the Contact

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
String cName = name.getText().toString();
String cPhone = phone.getText().toString();
String cMail = email.getText().toString();
int cPhoneType = mContactPhoneTypes.get(mContactPhoneTypeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
int cEmailType = mContactEmailTypes.get(mContactEmailTypeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rowContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, mSelectedAccount.getType()).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, mSelectedAccount.getName()).build());  
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rowContactInsertIndex).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,cName).build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rowContactInsertIndex).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, cPhone).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, cPhoneType).build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rowContactInsertIndex).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, cMail).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, cEmailType).build());

try {
    ContentProviderResult[] res =  getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence txt = getString(R.string.contactCreationFailure);
    Toast.makeText(context, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table raw_contacts has no column named data1: , while compiling: INSERT INTO raw_contacts(contact_id, data1, raw_contact_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, put effort on your posts; they are the medium to make others **understand what you mean**. ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you're trying to insert into the "raw contacts" table ([`ContactsContract.RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html)), but using a column name (`ContactsContract.Data.DATA1`) related to the [`ContactsContracts.Data`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table. I'm not an Android developer, but [this page on `ContactsContract`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) may be useful. Basically you want to make sure you're inserting into the right table(s) with the right column(s).